# Reading sas datasets in c#

Tags: c#, sas, dataset, add-in

I am writing c# add-in for using it in sas enterprise guide. I need to read datasets from sas library via c#. How can I do that?

I inherited myClass from SAS.Tasks.Toolkit.SasTask as below

```
namespace AB.CD.SASAddin.EF
{
    [ClassId("11187e27-6c84-47f2-8700-9edaf8bf8634")]
    [Version(1.0)]
    [IconLocation("AB.CD.SASAddin.EF.GH.ico")]
    public class myClass : SAS.Tasks.Toolkit.SasTask
....
```

so at the InitializeComponent function if I set

> this.RequiresData = true;

It opens a dialog at the begining of add-in start. On the dialog I can select a dataset for calculations. But actually I need to read more than one datasets.

So how can I read any sas library dataset from c# at runtime?

```
private void InitializeComponent()
{
  this.RequiresData = true;
  this.GeneratesSasCode = false;
  this.GeneratesReportOutput = false;
  this.ProcsUsed = "ARBOR, SQL";
  this.ProductsRequired = "BASE";
  this.TaskCategory = "QQ";
  this.TaskDescription = "QQQ";
  this.TaskName = "XXX";
}
```

Comment: You're outside of the area I'm familiar with.  However, I would recommend looking up Chris Hemedinger's SAS blog, as he is the main person I've seen writing about using .NET with SAS/EG.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For reading SAS Data in .Net I Used ADO and ADO.NET. You can find detailed in [here](http://support.sas.com/kb/25/276.html)